# how to make a 10X6 grid with each cell filled with a text view in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new in android.Please tell me how i can make a grid with 10 rows and 6 columns,and each cell filled with text views.I want to fill the text of each cell with different values,by click on a button.
i make a grid using table layout,with 10 rows and 60 text views,but i think it is not the right way to do this. 
Please provide me source code for this.
Thanks in advance...my java file..and xml files are here...

```
    TableLayout t1 =(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout)
// TableRow [] tr = new TableRow[10];  
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    TextView [] tv = new TextView[20];
    int j=0;
    int k=0;
   //for inserting 10 rows..
    for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
    {
        String cnt; 
        tv[j] = new TextView(this);
       TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
       TextView ttv = new TextView(this);
     //  TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        //to put a space between cells
    //tv1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tv1.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0); 
        tv1.setWidth(30);
        tv1.setHeight(45);
        tv1.setText("");


         //to put digits in text views...      
    //ttv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        ttv.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0); 
        ttv.setWidth(60);
        ttv.setHeight(45);
        ttv.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        ttv.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
        ttv.setTextSize(25);
        cnt=""+k+"";
        ttv.setText(cnt);
        k++;

        // to put symbols store in an array using a button click...the code of button and array in dnt show here...
   // tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tv[j].setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0); 
        tv[j].setWidth(60);
        tv[j].setHeight(45);
        tv[j].setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
        tv[j].setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        tv[j].setTextSize(25);
        //tv[j].setText("ab");

        tr.setPadding(0, 1, 0, 1); 

        tr.addView(tv1);
        tr.addView(ttv);
        tr.addView(tv[j]);

    j++;
    tr.addView(tv1);
        tr.addView(ttv);
        tr.addView(tv[j]);

    j++;
    tr.addView(tv1);
        tr.addView(ttv);
        tr.addView(tv[j]);   
        t1.addView(tr);

    }
```

Comment: i use table layout class and table row class with for loop to add multiple rows..but adding multiple text views in every row...making problm.......while single text view per row...executes normally.....

Comment: i also put my table layout in xml file into the scroll layout...so that i can scroll the table...

Answer (score 1):

You wont get the codez. So dont ask for it. I learnt it very early so suggesting you to try and do the coding yourself. We will only help if we see that you actually did do something yourself.

Anyways, using `GridLayout` would be better. Include `TextView` in your layout and in the `onClick()` of your button just change the text of the respective TextViews like this -

```
tv1.setText("1st changed");
tv2.setText("2nd changed");
```

and so on.

Ofcourse you need to find `tv1` and `tv2` ... also.

```
TextView tv1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
```

Comment: thank you sir....for help.but sir,if i have 6 cells in each of 10 rows.......then i have to write find view by id....60 times.......and i think it is not the right way to do this........so...please help me.....

Comment: since you will be using 60 `TextViews`,you need to write it 60 times. And whats the harm in that? Cant you copy paste? . And since TextView is an inbuilt class,you cannot create array of objects to use in a loop. Please correct me if there is any other way to create the objects of TextViews.

Comment: may be u r right......i dnt know much about it..but is it a only way to do this...???if some one wats to draw..a 10x10 table...then he has to write it 100 times...???is it good for a mobile application..where code must be efficient.....i create a array of object of text view class..it does nt give errors...but at run time...application,does not run...it forcly closed......if any how..it can be created using loops...then code must be very small and efficient also.....i think GRID VIEW can be a option,,,,but i unable to use it....as i didint know much about it.....

Answer (score 0):

in your XML for gridview set one more attribute

```
android:numColumns="6"
```

for setting 6 columns in a row.

Then `set adapter with length of 60 element` and you will get 10X6 Grid

Comment: thanks....but how i can change text of these cells,using java code,as i know to change the text of any text view,i have to use their id,and to find 60 text view,i have to write 60 times find view by id....i think it is not the right way......so i want  to make such table with 6 cells in each row..using java code...and edit their texts...when click on a button......please suggest me for this.....

Comment: @tushi0407 see [this](http://android-vogue.blogspot.in/2011/06/custom-gridview-in-android-with.html) you need to make same without imageview..and where they given noOfColumns=3 give 6

Comment: @frankenstein....thanks.....but i want to use table layout..and it must be posible..as when i want to add single text view in a single row,,it runs,,,